# Удобное DateTimePicker для выбора дата и время

Tags: c#

Работаю в проекте работающие в терминальной апарать (в c#). Я использовал из стандартное DateTimePicker для выбора дата и время, но DateTimePicker не подходить для выбора дата и время в терминальное апарат.
Вопрос: Мне нужно DateTimePicker dialog как у android очень удобно для выбора дата и время

Comment: Winforms? WPF?.

Comment: У меня вес проект на win forms, можно использовать wpf на част проекта

Comment: Вопрос ваш к чему именно относится? Добавьте соответствующий тег.

Comment: Поищите в nuget, если там нет то не судьба, меняйте фреймворк на более попсовый.